# Tire popped and shredded inside, Should I attempt an at home repair or buy wheels and drive it to a mechanic?

Tags: tires, gmc, yukon

So my bearings were messed up and as I was coming home one night the right tire popped on me and I freaked and kept driving home. Once I got home I had realized the tire fell off the rim and shredded the inside, should I just attempt to put a wheel back on and take it to the mechanics? Or can I just repair it at home?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What do you mean by "fix it"? If you've shredded the tire, it's done for. If you've driven it on the rim for any amount of distance, it's most likely done for as well. If you don't have a spare, beg, borrow, or steal one, because trying to drive on the original is a no go.

Comment: Ugh, based on that response i'm for sure going to have to go to a mechanic. I drove on it home so the rim is gone for as well

Comment: How old is the car? You'll need a rim anyway, go get one from a junkyard or something. Stop by the tire place as you'll be needing one of those too, and with new tire fit to replacement rim, bolt it on the faulty wheel.  You should know how to change a tire anyway, good practice doing it at home with access to tools and cleanup sinks.

Comment: 2007 gmc Yukon, and yeah I can change a tire. Thanks!

Comment: @Jose, you should have a space tire you can put on to get to a tire shop. Why would you try and fix a tire that's in tatters?

Comment: Can you add a photo of the damaged tire?

Answer (score 2):

If your tire is "shredded" as you describe, it is beyond repair.  There is no way to put that tire back on your rim.  Either use your spare tire on your car or use another vehicle to get the rim over to the tire shop, and buy a new tire.